# open the app from the notification action

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications

My notification has an action for which an event occurs inside the application, I want to open the application if the application is minimized. I tried to do this, but it doesn't work for some reason, and sometimes the application crashes :(

action:

```
val answerIntent = Intent(context, ActionReceiver::class.java).apply {
    action = "ACTION_ANSWER"
}

val answerPendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, acceptPendingId, answerIntent, 0)
```

Receiver

```
"ACTION_ANSWER" -> {
    if (!singleton.isAppInForeground(context)) {
        val openAppIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        context.startActivity(openAppIntent)
    }
    ...any code
}
```

isAppInForeground

```
fun isAppInForeground(context: Context): Boolean {
        val activityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
        val runningAppProcesses = activityManager.runningAppProcesses ?: return false
        for (processInfo in runningAppProcesses) {
            if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                if (processInfo.processName == context.packageName) {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#notification-trampolines):

> To improve app performance and UX, apps that target Android 12 or higher can't start activities from services or broadcast receivers that are used as notification trampolines.

This means that you cannot call `startActivity()` from the `BroadcastReceiver` that was invoked from the notification action. Doing so would result in an `AndroidRuntmeException`.

You can, however make the notification action directly launch the `Activity` instead of the `BroadcastReceiver`. To perform some additional actions you would have to do it within the launched `Activity` - you can achieve this by e.g. providing an `Intent` with information about the origin of the launch. In this case consider using [onNewIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)).